# What's the best way to call a list that has been created by 'range'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to reference listNum under def fibonnaci() function, but I am getting the following error: TypeError: 'range' object is not callable. How to fix this problem?

```
count = 0
fibC = 1
def fibonnaci():
    listNum = range(1,400)

    listFib = list()
    for num in listNum:
        number =  listNum(num - 1) + listNum(num - 2)
        listFib.append(number)
    return listFib

def numberOfFibonnaci(numbers):
    fibonnaci()
    while count < numbers:
        print(listFib[fibC+i])
        count += 1
        i += 1

def main():
    askF = input("Enter number of Fibonnaci")
    numberOfFibonnaci(askF)

main()
```

Expect to reference the integer before the designated one and add to the integer two spaces in a list before it.

Instead, get this error: TypeError: 'range' object is not callable.

Comment: Did you mean `listNum[num - 1] + listNum[num - 2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the items of listNum by index, using square brackets `[]`:

```
count = 0
fibC = 1


def fibonnaci():
    listNum = range(1, 400)

    listFib = list()
    for num in listNum:
        number = listNum[num - 1] + listNum[num - 2]  # you need to access by index!
        listFib.append(number)
    return listFib


def numberOfFibonnaci(numbers):
    listFib = fibonnaci()
    i = 0
    while i < numbers:
        print(listFib[fibC + i])
        i += 1


def main():
    askF = input("Enter number of Fibonnaci")
    numberOfFibonnaci(int(askF))

main()
```

Outputs:

```
Enter number of Fibonnaci12
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25
```

Answer (score 0):

Range is used to create an iterator for your loops, so you can not try to call it. If you want a list of numbers within a range, you can try using a list comprehension. It would look something like:

`listNum = [i for i in range(1,400)]` where listNum becomes a list containing entries from 1 to 399

documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: you don't need list comprehension but `listNum = list(range(1,400))`

Comment: I believe you get the same thing using both methods.

Comment: yes you can get the same result with both method but `list()` is shorter to write and code is more readable.

Comment: That it does! Thank you for the tip!